# why css use inline-block must be add pseudo element (let vertical-align:middle work)

Tags: html, css

```css
    .pseudo{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        text-align:center;

    }
    .pseudo:before{
        content:"";
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        height:100%;
    }
    .pseudo p{
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pseudo">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

This is my html & css code. my question is why i must use pseudo element the vertical-align:middle can work .
it's not work(vertical-align:middle) if write like this

```
.pseudo{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
```

}

Comment: please consider editing your question- it is not very clear... the `before` element is used to vetically align the `p` inside the `div`....

Comment: dude... your grammar, and spelling... please fix!

Comment: sorry my english is poor i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property applies to the element of the text line (unless you apply it to something with `display:table-cell`), so keywords like `center`, `top`, and `bottom` are calculated from the height of the text line (the so called [line box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#line-box)). The height of this line box is calculated basically from the heights of the inline elements that make this line (texts, images, inline blocks etc.), as well as their positions relative to each other (affected by some `vertical-align` values).

Without the pseudo element, the height of your line box is determined by the height of the text itself, so the text fits the whole line box, so [its vertical midpoint](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) is already aligned with the line box vertical midpoint, so applying `vertical-align:middle` changes nothing. But the inline block with 100% container height makes the line box (at least) as tall as this inline block (which means that the line box becomes as tall as the container). And aligning the vertical midpoint of the text with the vertical midpoint of this tall line box also makes the text visually centered in the container.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not know how a pseudo class works, here is what you should do:

1. The definition of pseudo is: "not genuine; sham." (tku [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20pseudo))
2. Go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) (Mozilla Developer Network) and read about pseudo classes.

A quick excerpt from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) is:

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a special state of the element to be selected. For example :hover will apply a style when the user hovers over the element specified by the selector.

Basically, you could have class `.foo`. Now let's say you want to style it when you hover over it. You *could* use Javascript, and *add* a class with the styles you want to use for hovering (using event listeners), but that is unnecessary and wasteful. Instead, you add a `pseudo` (remember: "not genuine; sham") class. So its a class, but it's not really a class. A pseudo class is defined with a `:` after the selector and before the pseudo class. For example:

- `span:hover`
- `.my-class:first-child`
- `#id-4-me:not(#id-not-4-me)`

etc.

There are also pseudo elements. They are defined with `::`. You can read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

In the future, please research your question before asking it, in alignment with the stackoverflow guidelines on [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `::after` is a pseudo element, not pseudo class. It can be written with single colon instead of double colon (along with 3 other pseudo elements) because these pseudo elements were introduced prior to CSS Selectors level 3 spec that introduced this syntax distinction. In earlier CSS specs both pseudo classes and pseudo elements had single colon, so for these 4 pseudo elements this syntax is kept specifically for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn yes, you are correct. If you want to edit my entry by all means do so (I made it "community wiki" so that it would be edited by the group)